# update textview without any buttons

Tags: android, textview

I have 2 edittext fields empty and i want to when i type numbers inside the two fields a 3rd textview will automatically get the division of the 2 above edittexts. *So no buttons to calculate that etc.*

The thing is when i enter one number on any field the app gets force closed. Here is my code and the logcat:

```
    amount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            AddFuelActivity.this.updateValue();
        }

    });

    litres.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            AddFuelActivity.this.updateValue();
        }

    });


protected void updateValue() {
    int amountInt = Integer.parseInt(amount.getText().toString());
    int litresInt = Integer.parseInt(litres.getText().toString());
    float priceFuelAuto = 0;
    priceFuelAuto = amountInt / litresInt;
    fuelPrice.setText("€ " + priceFuelAuto);
}
```

logcat errors: i think these are the important ones.

```
01-22 13:23:21.650: E/AndroidRuntime(671): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
01-22 13:23:21.650: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
01-22 13:23:21.650: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
01-22 13:23:21.650: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
01-22 13:23:21.650: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  atcom.example.mycarfuel.AddFuelActivity.updateValue(AddFuelActivity.java:155)
01-22 13:23:21.650: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  atcom.example.mycarfuel.AddFuelActivity$2.onTextChanged(AddFuelActivity.java:67)
```

I fixed my code. Here is what i did:

```
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        if (litres.length() > 0) {
            AddFuelActivity.this.updateValue();
        }
    }
```

and

```
    int amountInt = 0;
    int litresInt = 0;
    try {
        amountInt = Integer.parseInt(amount.getText().toString());
        litresInt = Integer.parseInt(litres.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        litresInt = 0;
        amountInt = 0;
    }
    if(amountInt !=0 && litresInt != 0){
        float priceFuelAuto = 0;
        priceFuelAuto = amountInt / litresInt;
        fuelPrice.setText("€ " + priceFuelAuto);
    }
```

thank you for your replies people

Comment: Its bcoz you are trying to compare a empty string which is not a valid integer.

Comment: yea the thing is that it captured and stoped my program as soon as i entered only 1 number. Thats y all were 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(edittext1.length()!=0){
            updateValue() 

            }
            else{
                edittext2.setText("");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

just write below code..

```
 amount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
             if(s.length()>0)     <<<<===Just put this condition
            AddFuelActivity.this.updateValue();
        }

    });

    litres.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) 
        {
             if(s.length()>0)     <<<<===Just put this condition
            AddFuelActivity.this.updateValue();
        }

    });


protected void updateValue() {
    int amountInt = Integer.parseInt(amount.getText().toString());
    int litresInt = Integer.parseInt(litres.getText().toString());
    float priceFuelAuto = 0;
    priceFuelAuto = amountInt / litresInt;
    fuelPrice.setText("€ " + priceFuelAuto);
}
```